# Single point of failure: File and Print Server

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a Documentum farm where we have Content servers, application servers and web servers. We have been able to eliminate single point of failure from these components by using clustering and load balancing.

We also have one file and print server where content is stored temporarily and then picked up by Captiva.

Can anyone tell me how do I remove the single point of failure from File and Print server. (Its a Windows Server 2003 File and Print Server) ?

Comment: No, We are not doing any printing. Its just for storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention "File and Print" although its not clear if you're doing any printing in this setup. If not, then you could set up a [Distributed File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)) between 2 or more file servers.

You could probably do this using shared storage and a 2-node cluster, but I think that'd probably be overkill and not worth the effort.